# Share info from class component in to function component with useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, use-state

```
//parent
const [mailArray, setMailArray] = useState([]);

 return (
          <StyledInputBox>
            <Chips setMailArray={setMailArray} />  //does not work
          </StyledInputBox>
          )
          
//children <<Chips>>
export default class Chips extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [''],
    value: '',
    error: null,
  };
}
```

class component <> is children of function component. I want to get info from children's state into a parent with props and useState.

Comment: Why you use class component for your children component? and whats is your mean of this question could you explain more ?

Comment: How can I pass >>setMailArray<< as a prop and how to give info it in the class component

Comment: You can't pass useState as a prop to a component you can pass a function or a variable with props!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your mailArray in your parent and pass it to your child component. Or if you want to change your mailArray in your child component you should pass a function to your Chips component that give a parameter that it trigger when for example you click on an element in your Chips component like below:

```js
const changeMail = (value) => {
setMailArray(value)
}
 return (
          <StyledInputBox>
            <Chips onChange={changeMail} />  //does not work
          </StyledInputBox>
          )
```

and in your Chips component should be for example some code like below:

```js
render() {
return (<div onClick={this.props.onChange('some value')}>chips component</div>)
}
```